# WPF ItemsSource Binding in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've created a custom control for selecting States in my application, called StateSelector. If I place it in my UserControl and bind the ItemsSource (through a custom property called StateList) it works fine. But using the same binding in a DataTemplate does not work.

Here is my StateSelector.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.StateSelector"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
    Height="21" Width="60">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="0"
              Name="cboState"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentState, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=StateList, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Code}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here is my StateSelector.xaml.cs

```
public class StateSelector : UserControl
{
    public ObservableCollection<State> StateList
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<State>)GetValue(StateListProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StateListProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StateListProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("StateList", typeof(ObservableCollection<State>), typeof(StateSelector));

    public State CurrentState
    {
        get{ return (State)GetValue(CurrentStateProperty); }
        set{ SetValue(CurrentStateProperty, value); }
    }
    public static DependencyProperty CurrentStateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentState", typeof(State), typeof(StateSelector));

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor for StateSelector
    /// </summary>
    public StateSelector()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Then in the containing UserControl's Constructor I populate an ObservableCollection with State objects.
Here is MyDisplay.xaml.cs

```
public class MyDisplay : UserControl
{
    private static DependencyProperty StateListProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("StateList", typeof(ObservableCollection<State>), typeof(RateTableDisplay));
    public ObservableCollection<State> StateList
    {
        get{ return (ObservableCollection<State>)GetValue(StateListProperty); }
        set{ SetValue(StateListProperty, value); }
    }

    // Code to define SourceObject as seen in following XAML omitted

    public MyDisplay()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        StateManager stateManager = new StateManager();
        StateList = new ObservableCollection<State>(stateManager.GetAll(Context));
    }
}
```

In the XAML of MyDisplay I have a section that uses the StateSelector as is and another that uses it in a DataTemplate.
Here is MyDisplay.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.MyDisplay"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
    Height="Auto" Width="Auto"
    Name="_this"
    DataContext="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=SourceObject}">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="OriginStateCellTemplate">
            <Local:StateSelector StateList="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=StateList}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<!-- Unrelated XAML omitted -->
<!-- The StateSelector below gets populated properly -->
<StackPanel>
    <Local:StateSelector Grid.Column="3" StateList="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=StateList}" x:Name="cmbMasterOriginState" />
</StackPanel>

<!-- More Unrelated XAML omitted -->
<!-- The StateSelector below does not get populated at all -->
<StackPanel>
    <ListView Height="610">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="origStateCol" Width="85" CellTemplate="{StaticResource OriginStateCellTemplate}">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Click="header_Click" Tag="OriginState">Origin State</GridViewColumnHeader>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView> 
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

I've tried different ways to bind the StateList such as these:

```
StateList="{Binding Path=StateList, Source={x:Reference _this}}"
StateList="{Binding Path=StateList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
```

But no such luck. I can't figure out why the ItemsSource is not being populated in the DataTemplate example. It works fine outside of the DataTemplate. I'm not getting any binding errors in the Output of Debug in Visual Studio either.

When searching I found quite a few related issues but they all seemed to be trying to use a general DataContext defined in the top UserControl element. I'm specifically trying to use a property of the UserControl itself.

Any ideas?

Comment: You seem to have bound to something called "`SourceObject`" in your control.  I don't see anywhere where you've defined it.  Also, why would you simply not bind to the control's `DataContext`?

Comment: BTW, assinging to the DataContext of the control means you don't have to deal with the control's DataContext binding in XAML.

Comment: I have a comment regarding SourceObject in MyDisplay.xaml.cs example. I do assign the DataContext to SourceObject which is the object this form focuses on. So most of my bindings are very simple. This particular "StateSelector" I want bound to a property of MyDisplay rather than to a property of MyDisplay.SourceObject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your `UserControl` and then create properties for `StateList` and then on the setter raise the property changed event provided by the `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: I tried to implement this on MyDisplay for StateList and it didn't help. Is setting my StateList property as a DependencyProperty not adequate? Also can you please explain why I would need INotifyPropertyChanged to fix the issue with the binding inside a DataTemplate when the binding for a non-templated control would work?

Comment: No, you create dependency properties if you want them to be bindable for your ViewModel. You are creating the property behind the actual user control code which is the View. Where it has access to your controls. What's the point of doing bindings in the first place? Why not just set the `ItemsSource` directly to `StateList`

Comment: Do you mean set the ItemsSource of StateSelector programmatically? I'm trying to do as much in WPF as I can. But in any case, it still doesn't explain why the binding works outside of a DataTemplate but not inside one.

Comment: Because data templates are executed later, the control looked like it work but in reality it was able to get the value of the property. You need `INPC` to tell the UI "hey there's a new value, update your value"

Comment: I'm an idiot. There was code that was manipulating the CellTemplate in the background. The issue was not related to binding at all. I flagged my own post asking what should be done. I'd like to delete it because the question is deceiving, but your answer is definitely right. I'll accept it and see what the mods say. Thanks for your help :)